# How to check in Coded UI Test that your secondary tile is pinned

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

How to check if the secondary tile is pinned from the Coded UI Test. Also is it possible to get tile information such as colour?

Answer (score -1):

The sample demonstrates how to

determine whether a particular tile is currently pinned to the Start screen:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Secondary-Tiles-Sample-edf2a178

Comment: You can't access xaml elements directly from coded UI test.